# remote connection config in terminator

Tags: ssh, configuration, remote, gnome-terminator

I'm using terminator and would like it to start up pre-configured with remote connections established, I do achieve this by setting `ssh user@host` in the `command =` field in `~/.config/terminator/config` for my respective `terminator` child. Now, as soon as I reboot that rtemote host, my terminator child closes down which is not optimal;, I would like it to just terminate the connection but not close the whole window. How can I get around this? I haven'yt tried it yet but something like `ssh localhost ssh user@host` might work? Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
ssh host; echo "Reconnect?"; while read; do ssh host; echo "Reconnect?"; done
```

in your command should do the job. It connects to your host and when the connection is lost, it asks you for a reconnect.

Or just simply as you wanted:

```
ssh host; bash
```

will connect to your host and when the connection ends, it gives you new shell